# C++ program not compiling with Clang and visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64, llvm-clang

I'm trying to compile the source code as described in this tutorial with visual c++ 2010 express.
http://kevinaboos.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/clang-tutorial-part-ii-libtooling-example/

The full source code is over here.
https://github.com/kevinaboos/LibToolingExample

I have used the executable provided in this link to install LLVM. 
I can't post the complete error message due to formatting issues. But 
I will try to give as much information as I can.
When I'm trying to build the solution , I get the following errors :-

```
argument unused during compilation warnings.
C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\include\llvm/Support/Compiler.h(57,1): error : LLVM requires at least MSVC 2012.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocnum(228,53): error : definition of dllimport static field not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\include\llvm/ADT/IntrusiveRefCntPtr.h(26,9): fatal error : 'atomic' file not found
```

I'm using windows-7 64 bit.
I've linked the header files and libraries by changing the project properties.
I'm new to building c++ applications. Please help.

Comment: Would it work with MSVC2012 as suggested in the error message?

Comment: i don't have visual c++ 2012

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear

Comment: @SouravMukherjee If i remembered it correctly, MSVC is a free download.

Comment: MSVC 2012 says :- VC\include\xstring(2195,3): error : cannot compile this try statement yet expanded from macro '_TRY_BEGIN'
   #define _TRY_BEGIN     try {                     on compiling a simple hello world program. this is the hello world program i was trying to compile:-  # include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 cout<<"hello world";
}   ... Please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For MSVC 2012 build error, found a solution [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2a4o7x/llvm_project_blog_clangllvm_on_windows_update/)

According to [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html), Exceptions and SEH are not supported yet. You have to disable it.

To disable exception in Visual Studio, please open Project Properties and go to C/C++, Preprocessor, then add **_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0** to Preprocessor Definitions.